# Bash loop control while if else with a return

Tags: bash, while-loop

I need to return a true or false if I find a value within a file. I parse the file and if the value is located once which is enough, I want to break and return a true else return false. On top of it I need to pass the file into this check function. I'm trying to only use bash.

```
is_file_contains_VAR(){
    VARFILENAME=$1

    while read LINE
    do
        if echo "$LINE" | grep -q "$VAR"; then
            break
            return 0   
        else
            return 1
        fi
    done < $VARFILENAME
}
```

Comment: First thing you might want to do here is ask yourself what a statement _immediately after_ a `break` might do....

Comment: A break should get me out of the while at least I'm hoping. I don't want it to continue through the whole file.

Comment: Right so the `return 0` won't be executed in that case.

Comment: Would it make more sense to have the return 0 after the while? so after the last line done < $VARFILENAME

Comment: Yes but that is still only the first problem.  Your code is always returning a value the _first_ time through the loop.  You need to wait until you have gone through the whole file without seeing VAR in order to return 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep -q` already does what you want: it will abort as soon as it finds the string in question. So you can just write:

```
function is_file_contains_VAR () {
    grep -q -e "$VAR" "$1"
}
```

(Note: the `-e` is in case `"$VAR"` starts with a hyphen.)

But for educational purposes . . . to write this as a loop, what you would want is to `return 0` as soon as there's a match, and only `return 1` at the very end, if you never find a match:

```
function is_file_contains_VAR () {
    local VARFILENAME="$1"
    local LINE
    while IFS= read -r LINE ; do
        if grep -q -e "$VAR" <<< "$LINE" ; then
             return 0
        fi
    done < "$VARFILENAME"
    return 1
}
```

Comment: Also, if using the `bash` loop shown, use `bash`'s built-in regular expression support instead of forking a `grep` process: `if [[ "$LINE" =~ $VAR ]]; then`. You would need to make sure that `VAR` conforms to the regular expressions understood by `bash`.

Comment: what do you mean by "forking" a grep?  Does this open up a new thread is what you mean?  Is grep natively supported in bash, meaning I can use it on any machine with bash?

Comment: @MAXGEN: Not "forking a `grep`", but "forking a `grep` **process**"; that is, using `fork()` to create a new process, which will then be used to run `grep`. (If you're not familiar with forking and processes, then please Google them; I can't/won't explain them in a short comment.) Re: "Is grep natively supported in bash, meaning I can use it on any machine with bash?": No. They are separate programs. If you have bash, you'll *usually* have grep, but there are plenty of exceptions.